# System restore/system rollback - possible in my scenario?

Tags: firefox, data-recovery, restore

I was using a site which wrote over login data on Mozilla. Basically, I created an account with email+password and was assigned a unique wallet address. Then I created a second account with a new email + password but found out that this overwrites access to the first unique wallet address that I created. I'm skipping over some details here for the sake of the reader's time - there's more to it than that.

The data came from Mozilla and is automatically saved to local browsing data. My hope here is that if I can "roll back" or system restore to before the incident (yesterday afternoon), then I can undo this and reaccess the first unique wallet address. The problem is, I have never manually backed up data.

Is there anything I can do to basically go back in time? I don't know if this is allowed here and will remove if it is not, but I'm offering a bounty (a few thousand USD) for a fix to this.

Using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: Do I understand this correctly that you had, at some point, stored a set of account credentials in Firefox’ integrated password store and that this password store was at the time connected to and synchronised with a *Mozilla Sync* account to which you still have access? Now these particular credentials in the store were removed/replaced and this change was replicated to the same *Mozilla Sync* account, right?

Comment: It would help if you split your wall of text into paragraphs or better yet an [itemised list](/editing-help#simple-lists) to make it easier to read and establish a clear time line of events.

Comment: I should have included that I'm not tech savvy at all. I just use linux because I got locked out of Windows and customer support was useless. So, most terminology is over my head

Comment: I don't know where the account credentials are stored. Website devs just said it was stored locally as browser data.  They did not say exactly where the files are stored, but said it was impossible to recover. They implied that the only hope for recovering the account was a system recovery. I'm exploring if system recovery is possible at this point, given I have never manually backed up

Answer (score 1):

There's no back-up or system restoration process set up in Ubuntu out of the box. If you didn't set one up yourself there's no back-up.

If you selected ext4, the default file system type, for the user home directory during Ubuntu's installation (or had Ubuntu partition the drive for you) any change to Firefox’ on-disk password store was *overwritten in place*. On a hard disk drive that means the previous data is gone and there's no significant chance for recovery. On a solid state drive there's a slim chance that a well equipped data recovery lab may be able to extract the old data from the recycled storage blocks.

Comment: if i was looking for a local company to try and recover the data, what would i look for?

Comment: @Kremer *In general* please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question. The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. *However* your *particular* follow-up question is unrelated to Ubuntu and off topic on Ask Ubuntu. It may be on topic over at [SU]. Thanks.